# Can I expand a single string with the union of several regular expressions in python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm hacking on a [package](http://code.google.com/p/ruffus/) that transforms file types, allowing the user to specify the transformation (a python function) and a regular expression for how the filename is to be changed.

In one case, I have a series of regexes and a single output string which I'd like to be expanded with the union of all my regex groups:

```
import re
re_strings = ['(.*).txt', '(.*).ogg', 'another(?P<name>.*)']
regexes = map(re.compile, re_strings]
input_files = ['cats.txt', 'music.ogg', 'anotherpilgrim.xls']
matches = [regexes[i].match(input_files[i]) for i in range(len(regexes))]

outputstr = 'Text file about: \1, audio file about: \2, and another file on \g<name>.'
# should be 'Text file about: cats, audio file about: music, and another file on pilgrim.xls'
```

I'd like to have `outputstr` be expanded with the union of the regular expressions (perhaps concatenation makes more sense for the `\2` reference?).  I could concatenate the re's, separating them by some unused character:

```
final_re = re.compile('\n'.join(re_strings))
final_files = '\n'.join(input_files)
match = final_re.search(final_files)
```

But this forces the re's to match the entire file, not just some portion of the filename.  I can put in a catch-all group between the files a la `(.*?)` but that will surely mess up the group references and it might mess up the original patterns (which I have no control over). I guess I could also force named groups everywhere, then union all the regex .groupdict()s...

Python doesn't allow partial expansion so all group references have to be valid, so there's no chance of doing a series of expansions for the groupdict anyway like:

```
for m in matches:
    outputstr = m.expand(outputstr)
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Why not use `'Text file about: {0[0]}, audio file about: {1[0]}, and another file on {2[0]}.'.format(*(m.groups() for matches))` instead?

Comment: Off topic, but you could make you iteration a little cleaner like this: `[r.match(f) for (f,r) in zip(input_files, regexes)]`

Comment: To be a bit clearer, I don't have control over the contents of the regexes, nor do I have control over the contents of `outputstr`. @larsks, good tip. @MartijnPieters, using a format match instead of an re expansion might do the trick... will test.

Comment: Building on your idea @MartijnPieters, I can also include named groups: `outputstr.format(*[{i : m.group(i) for i in range(m.lastindex) + m.groupdict().keys()} for m in matches])`.  Fill out a proper answer and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, here is how to combine the results of several regular expression results, and make replacements across them all.

Given several query strings, and several regular expression matches:

```
import re

query_str = ["abcdyyy", "hijkzzz"]
re_pattern = [r"(a)(b)(?P<first_name>c)(d)",
              r"(h)(i)(?P<second_name>j)(k)"]

# match each separately
matches= [re.search(p,q) for p,q in 
          zip(re_pattern, query_str)]
```

We would like to make a substitution string combining the results of all the searches:

```
replacement = r"[\4_\g<first_name>_\2_\1:\5:\6:\8:\g<second_name>]"
```

To do this, we need to:

1. Merge the search results
2. Have a proxy in place of the merged results (match_substitute)
3. Have a proxy object to handle named groups e.g. "first_name" (pattern_substitute)

This is handled by the following code. The results are in "result":

```
import sre_parse

#
#   dummy object to provide group() function and "string" member variable
#
class match_substitute:
    def __init__(self, matches): 
        self.data = []
        for m in matches:
            self.data.extend(m.groups())
        self.string = ""
    # regular expression groups count from 1 not from zero!
    def group(self, ii):
        return self.data[ii - 1]



#
#   dummy object to provide groupindex dictionary for named groups
#
class pattern_substitute:
    def __init__(self, matches, re_pattern): 
        #
        #   Named group support
        #   Increment indices so they are point to the correct position
        #       in the merged list of matching groups
        #
        self.groupindex = dict()
        offset = 0
        for p, m in zip(re_pattern, matches):
            for k,v in sre_parse.parse(p).pattern.groupdict.iteritems():
                self.groupindex[k] = v + offset
            offset += len(m.groups())



match   = match_substitute(matches)
pattern = pattern_substitute(matches, re_pattern)

#
#   parse and substitute
#
template = sre_parse.parse_template(replacement, pattern)
result = sre_parse.expand_template(template, match)
```